# Why did the 24th chromosome pair turn people into monsters instead of superhumans?

Tags: plot-explanation, doom-2005

In *Doom* (2005), UAC Facility scientist tested their mutations on criminals but they are turning into monsters instead of superhumans. According to Samantha, a scientist working as archaeological staff, a 24th pair chromosome make the human strong & cancerless being.

> The extra pair makes her super strong, super fit, super intelligent.

Then why didn't happen like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It's genetic

> Grimm determines that their genetics have been altered by the addition of the Martian chromosome; however, the **chromosome seems to "choose"** whether it causes the person to be superhuman or a monster, **apparently able to determine on a genetic level whether a person has the capacity to be evil**.
>
> <sup>[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0419706/synopsis?ref_=tt_stry_pl)</sup>